# boost split can not split Chinese sentence

Tags: c++, boost, split, chinese-locale

I have a Chinese sentence, I want to split it with Chinese punctuation. But it failed. I used utf-8 encoding in file.

```
std::string src = "使用boost split失败了，不知道什么原因。有人可以告诉我吗？谢谢！";

boost::split(results, src, boost::is_any_of(",.，。"));
```

The split results is:

```
["使用boost split失败了", "", "", "不知道�", "么原因", "", "", "有人可以告诉我吗", "", "�谢谢", "", "�"]
```

Boost split can not split words in Chinese? Some one can tell me the reason? thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I find that the C++11 regex can solve this problem:

```
std::regex regex("，|。|！|？");
std::string src = "使用boost split失败了，不知道什么原因。有人可以告诉我吗？谢谢！";

std::sregex_token_iterator iterator(src.begin(), src.end(), regex, -1);
std::sregex_token_iterator end;

for ( ; iterator != end; ++iterator) {
    std::string res = *iterator;
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
}

results:
使用boost split失败了
不知道什么原因
有人可以告诉我吗
谢谢
```

Why boost can't? Am I used the wrong method?

Comment: Here, the regex is explicitly dividing the pattern into the correct byte-sequences to match (instead of just matching any of the bytes in the pattern as if they were characters). Note that this depends on the [normalization of the input/pattern strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence)

Answer (score 1):

Boost split thinks treats the strings as std::strings: sequences of `char`: roughly "bytes" (or code units in UTF-8, I believe).

However, many of the code points in the source/pattern are multi-byte characters, this actually what's there (assuming UTF-8 source files):

```
std::string src {
  0xe4, 0xbd, 0xbf, 0xe7, 0x94, 0xa8, 0x62, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x73, 0x74, 0x20,
  0x73, 0x70, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x74, 0xe5, 0xa4, 0xb1, 0xe8, 0xb4, 0xa5, 0xe4,
  0xba, 0x86, 0xef, 0xbc, 0x8c, 0xe4, 0xb8, 0x8d, 0xe7, 0x9f, 0xa5, 0xe9,
  0x81, 0x93, 0xe4, 0xbb, 0x80, 0xe4, 0xb9, 0x88, 0xe5, 0x8e, 0x9f, 0xe5,
  0x9b, 0xa0, 0xe3, 0x80, 0x82, 0xe6, 0x9c, 0x89, 0xe4, 0xba, 0xba, 0xe5,
  0x8f, 0xaf, 0xe4, 0xbb, 0xa5, 0xe5, 0x91, 0x8a, 0xe8, 0xaf, 0x89, 0xe6,
  0x88, 0x91, 0xe5, 0x90, 0x97, 0xef, 0xbc, 0x9f, 0xe8, 0xb0, 0xa2, 0xe8,
  0xb0, 0xa2, 0xef, 0xbc, 0x81
};

boost::split(results, src, boost::is_any_of({
  0x2c, 0x2e, 0xef, 0xbc, 0x8c, 0xe3, 0x80, 0x82
}));
```

As you can see, it splits on any of 8 bytes (0x2c, 0x2e, 0xef, 0xbc, 0x8c, 0xe3, 0x80, 0x82), not the 4 code points you might have been expecting.

I /think/ I remember Boost Regex having more UNICODE support, other than that you can try converting all strings to UTF32 and use the algorithms you already used.

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/unicode.html

> You can only search strings that are encoded as sequences of wide characters, it is not possible to search UTF-8, or even UTF-16 on many platforms.

Looks like you should probably convert to UTF32 anyways. Alternatively you can use the ICU integration with boost::u32regex

Comment: UTF-32 isn't any better: there are still characters that consist of multiple code units (sic?) which will require you to normalize the unicode string first.

Comment: I disagree this wouldn't be any better. But yeah that's true too.

Comment: std::string used char to storage the data, here I used utf-8 encoded  sentence. The utf-8 size overflowed the char size. Maybe it caused the problem.

Comment: UTF-8 is just an encoding, so I wouldn't call encoding UNICODE codepoints as multibyte sequences "overflow" (overflow implies a loss of information). So yes, multi-byte encoding is the problem as my answer illustrated in detail. Not "maybe".